# Alternate way to get last and first record from database table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization, union

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id ASC  LIMIT 1 )DUMMY_ALIAS1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT * FROM customer  ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1)DUMMY_ALIAS11
```

what is other alternative way to get the last and first record , i think my query is not optimized

Comment: Are you actually having issues with your query? Assuming that `Customer_ID` is the clustering key on the `Customer` table (seems like a fair assumption) your query is probably already as good as it can be.

Comment: Dear @GarethD i want more optimized as it can be (~_~)

Comment: I get that, and applaud your attention to detail, but my point is the difference between the two methods posted below, and your method is likely to be unmeasurable. If you don't have a problem (which I don't imagine you do) then don't waste your time on such micro optimisations. I *really* hate to use the [Donald Knuth quote](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) regarding premature optimisation, but this really does fall into the 97% of times where you don't need to worry about it. You have already wasted more time on this than it is worth.

Comment: @GarethD I agree, the only way to make this query optimized is to use an index (but customer_id is probably a primary key, so it should be optimized already). Selecting from a subquery can make things slower, but not really on this context (and MySQL 5.7 will probably ignore the outer query anyway).

Comment: I testet your query and the two from answers on a 30M-rows table just for fun: all are executed in 0 msec (as expected). So i would take the one, wich ist most readable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MIN(customer_id) AS minCustomerId, 
                    MAX(customer_id) AS maxCustomerId 
             FROM customer
           ) AS b ON c.customer_id IN (minCustomerId, maxCustomerId);
```

Comment: yes dear its working fine . thanks a lot , will it be more fast ,optimized query

Comment: Based on `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%', I think this one is more efficient than fthiella's.  (I tried 5.6; older versions may be less efficient with that `IN`.)

Answer (score 3):

Your query is fine, there's no problem with it, but you can simplify it a little:

```
(SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM customer  ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

there's no need to use the outer query and the aliases, but don't forget to add an index on customer_id:

```
alter table customer add index idx_customer_id (customer_id);
```

or (probably better, but it depends on the context) to define it as a primary key:

```
alter table customer add primary key (customer_id);
```

this will make your query optimized.